# Subtypingclassing ndarray - how to construct from a normal ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, subtyping

Consider the code below:

```
class imarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
          strides=None, order=None):
        if isinstance(shape, np.ndarray):
            obj = shape #doesn't convert subtype.......
        else:
            obj = np.ndarray.__new__(subtype, shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides,
                             order)
        return obj

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return np.ndarray.__getitem__(self, key)





z = np.zeros([2,3])
x = imarray((2,3))
y = imarray(z)

print(y, type(y))
print(x, type(x))
```

The line `y = imarray(z)` should just create a copy and change the type of the array. (but imarray is a subclass of ndarray this should always work anyways).

How would one do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
obj = shape.view(imarray)
```